App con mas de dos mil imágenes se cuelga
estoy desarrollando una app para el estudio de plantas, en ella debo disponer mas de dos mil fotos de ellas.
Están guardadas en la carpeta res/drawable, el tamaño total es de unos 900MB, tienen formato *.jpg
Utilizo Picasso para el manejo de las mismas dentro de la app.
El emulador es API 30, el SDK target es 34 y el mínimo 24.
Utilizo un recyclerView con su adaptador correspondiente para una cardView que contiene la ficha de cada planta.
Al chequear la Lista <'planta'> allPlants que 'alimenta' al reciclerView (donde las recupero de la BDD de SQLITE) está todo OK.
Al correrla en el emulador se cuelga en la segunda o tercera ficha.
En el teléfono, con Android 9, o no se instala o inicia el proceso y cuando voy a rodar la app se cuelga y no  deja ningún aviso en el logcat.
¿Necesito permisos para WRITE_EXTERNAL-STORAGE al instalar?
¿Debo colocar las imágenes que quiero copiar al teléfono en alguna otra carpeta?
Muchas gracias.

Lo resolví cambiando el tamaño de la imagen con Picasso, poniendo un tamaño en función del tamaño de la pantalla, en el adaptador del recyclerView. Lo de los permisos no me ha hecho falta.
